# What is a difference between $VARNAME and ${VARNAME}?

Tags: bash, shell

I wonder what is a difference between `$VARNAME` and `${VARNAME}` in bash ?

Comment: One question to a question. You can ask about whether curly braces make a difference, or about single-vs-double-quotes, but putting both in one question is too broad.

Comment: For your second question, try `foo="$bar"` and `foo='$bar'` (where `bar` has already been defined), and you should see the difference.

Comment: Please refer to: <br/>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash <br/>

Comment: btw -- all-caps variable names are actually used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell; lowercase names are reserved for application use, and are thus generally what you should be using in your own code. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph (the spec is re: environment variables, but setting a regular shell variable automatically overwrites any like-named environment variable, making the convention necessarily apply in both places).